# How do I get svg vmin right?

Tags: svg

According to the standards I'm reading -- for example https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#viewport-relative-lengths -- a vmin unit should be 1% of the smallest dimension of the containing viewport.

Going for a minimal example illustrating my dilemma, this is square in my current instance of chrome:

```html
<svg><rect height="30vmin" width="30vmin" fill="red">
```

But this is not:

```html
<svg><rect height="50vmin" width="50vmin" fill="red">
```

Playing with variations on this theme (closing tags, adding width and height to the svg element, etc.) suggests that the rect is not using the svg viewport as its reference, but instead is using some containing browser context as its reference viewport.

So, my question is: how do I specify to the browser that I want vmin units to refer to the innermost containing svg viewport? (Specifically when working with svg elements embedded in html documents.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser support for those units that were added in CSS3 may still be spotty.  I haven't checked recently.

But the rule is that these units are resolved relative to the whole document.  So in a browser, that will be the whole browser window.

This SVGWG issue may help clarify things. 
 https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/207

> how do I specify to the browser that I want vmin units to refer to the innermost containing svg viewport?

You can use percentage values for coordinates,

```
<rect height="50%" width="50%" fill="red">
```

However in SVG, percentage values are always relative to their associated axis. So percentage width values are relative to the X axis, and percentage height values are relative to the Y axis.

Alternatively you could use a suitable `viewBox` and appropriate coordinate values relative to that viewBox.  For example, if your viewBox has a width and height of 100:

```
viewBox="0 0 100 100"
```

All coordinates values in the SVG would effectively be percentage values. However the same axis rule applies as described above.

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <!-- rectnagle 50% x 33.3% -->
  <rect width="50" height="33.3"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer as adequate for my purposes. That said, I should note that percent units are not always accepted in svg (for example, in polygons), and that they are not always specifically aligned with an axis (for example, in circle radius). (So overlaying a polygon on a centered circle with a percent is an... interesting exercise -- and your viewbox suggestion looks like a clue to the necessary approach.)